# How to check unsigned char pointer checking with zero in driver code?

Tags: c++, memory-management, driver

I wrote a driver code for query packet . but I got bluescreen issue and I took dump also . after analyzing I got error on particular line mentioned below . why this error occur ? can I check  `unsigned char pointer with zero` ?

my definitions :

```
typedef unsigned char u8_t ;
typedef unsigned char s8_t ;
typedef unsigned short u16_t ;
```

my function

```
void function1 (u8_t ntype , u16_t nvar , u8_t *pbuffer)
{
   HEADER packet = (HEADER)allocatemry( sizeof(HEADER) + (pbuffer == 0 ? 0 : var)) ;  //header is a structure with contain union . 

   packet->type = ntype ; 

   if ( pbuffer != 0 )  //got bluescreen issue . windbug pointed here 
    {
      packet->variant.variable = network(nvar) ;
    }

   else
    {
       packet->variant.variable = nvar ;
    }
}
```

please help me .

Comment: *I took dump also* :) :)

Comment: [OT] shouldn't `typedef unsigned char s8_t ;` be `typedef signed char s8_t ;`?

Comment: Can `allocatemry()` return null? Also if you allocate just `sizeof(HEADER)` is the buffer large enough to actually store the `->variant`?

Comment: this is like a function which return NULL to create mry

Comment: also I am doing " MCopyMemory(pPacket + 1, pBuffer, nVariant); " inside if loop .

Comment: It looks like you are only allocating the size of HEADER, which is a pointer to a struct.  You are not allocating enough space for the struct.

Comment: so how can I allocate enough space ?

Comment: What is HEADER defined as?

Comment: it is a structure like :   typedef struct  _MYHEADER {

Comment: typedef struct _MYHEADER 
{

u16_t   type ;
 
 union 
 {
    u16_t length ;
    u16_t variable;
 }variant;

}MYHEADER,*HEADER

Comment: Then allocate sizeof MYHEADER or *HEADER, not HEADER.

Comment: @roger identifiers that start with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved, and therefore not allowed. Why not get rid of the typedefs entirely and name your struct `MYHEADER` and use `MYHEADER*` for the pointers to avoid confusion?

Answer (score 2):

The error is very unlikely to have occurred on the shown line. The line before it or possibly after seem much more likely.

And the source of the problem is this:

```
HEADER packet = (HEADER)allocatemry( sizeof(HEADER) + (pbuffer == 0 ? 0 : var)) ; //header is a structure with contain union .
```

Unlike the comment at the end of the line claims, `HEADER` must actually be a pointer rathern than a structure. This is evidenced by it being a return type of allocation function and the indirection operator here: `packet->type`.

So, since `HEADER` is a pointer, your're allocating memory enough for a single pointer and possibly a few more bytes depending on `pbuffer` and `var` instead of allocating enough bytes for an object of some sort. If that is not enough memory for your object, then this results in an invalid memory access when the program assumes that enough memory was allocated.

You can get the number of needed bytes to store an object that can be pointed by `HEADER` like this: `sizeof std::remove_pointer<HEADER>::type`.

Now that you've revealed the actual type of the struct in a comment, this is a simpler way: `sizeof _MYHEADER`.

By the way, identifiers that begin with an underscore followed by an uppercase letter are reserved, so `_MYHEADER` is not allowed. I recommend getting rid of the typedefs entirely, name your struct `MYHEADER` and use `MYHEADER*` for the pointers to avoid confusion in the future.